# custom web component with vanilla javascript and validations

Tags: javascript, validation

I am working in a web component, but I want to add it validations with [javascript constrains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation), but It looks like this just work for inputs elements and my main container is a div.

I am not sure if it exists some workaround for this. I had tried to use an input with display none or size 0x0, but this dislike to me and does not work good.

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" required="" name="field1">
    <input type="text" required="" name="field2">
    <div name="mycustominput" myValidation="true">
        <!--
        children html elements render list and another things
        I want to validate this with the form
        -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are not attaching code, however, validation is for form components, not for single boxes (`<div>`). What do you try to validate into a div?

Comment: I believe he is referring to the pseudo selectors being placed on the input element rather than the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

if you try some inputs validate together like this:

```
<form id="passwordForm" novalidate>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Change Your Password</legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="password1">Password 1:</label>
            <input type="password" required id="password1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password2">Password 2:</label>
            <input type="password" required id="password2" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" />
</fieldset>
```

js

```
var password1 = document.getElementById('password1');
var password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

var checkPasswordValidity = function() {
    if (password1.value != password2.value) {
        password1.setCustomValidity('Passwords must match.');
    } else {
        password1.setCustomValidity('');
    }        
};

password1.addEventListener('change', checkPasswordValidity, false);
password2.addEventListener('change', checkPasswordValidity, false);

var form = document.getElementById('passwordForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    checkPasswordValidity();
    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Implement you own means of displaying error messages to the user here.
        password1.focus();
    }
}, false);
```

this link (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) is yours.

have a good day.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the issue is not the input components. The issue is to validate the div with setCustomValidity. that is not possible, so I want to find some workaround